# Поддержка шаблонов в языке Go

Tags: golang

Есть ли поддержка шаблонов в языке Go? Если нет, ожидается ли? Если ее не будет, кто какую альтернативу может предложить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шаблонов нет и не будет, хотя до выхода Go 1 велась весьма обширная дискуссия об их включении.

Альтернатива... смотря чего вы хотите от шаблонов. Если вам нужна возможность писать функции принимающие аргументы нескольких типов, то тут всё решается интерфейсами. Например так:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type myint int
type mystring string

type somethingThatHasName interface {
    Name() string
}

func (self mystring) Name() string {
    return "string"
}

func (self myint) Name() string {
    return "int"
}

func test(arg somethingThatHasName) {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", arg.Name())
}

func main() {
    i := myint(0)
    s := mystring("str")

    test(i)
    test(s)
}
```

Если не хочется городить интерфейсы, то можно просто задать тип для аргумента как `interface{}`, а потом привести его к любому типу с помощью [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

В общем с типами проблем нет, можно вовсе ввезде использовать `interface{}` и писать как на JavaScript, единственное, это всё будет проверяться во время выполнения.

Comment: Вообще, хотелось бы использовать шаблонные ф-и, те один код производит операции над разными типами (интерфейсами тут не обойтись).

Comment: C++ рулит!

Comment: > один код производит операции над разными типами (интерфейсами тут не обойтись).

можно пример?